# Constructor takes Integer but not String

Tags: julia

This works:

```
struct Comic
    endpoint::String
end

function Comic(id::Int)
    url = "https://xkcd.com/$id/info.0.json"
    Comic(url)
end


Comic(1)
```

It returns `Comic("https://xkcd.com/1/info.0.json")`.

This doesn't work:

```
struct Comic
    endpoint::String
end

function Comic(id::String)
    url = "https://xkcd.com/$id/info.0.json"
    Comic(url)
end


Comic("1")
```

It kills the Julia process.

Why doesn't the second example work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your code `Comic("1")` calls `Comic(id::String)`.

`Comic(id::String)` calls `Comic(url)` which again means calling `Comic(id::String)`

So you simply end up with an endless recursive loop.

Comment: At first I was confused why the first example doesn't cause the same loop. Now I see. `Comic(1)` calls `Comic(id::Int)`, which calls `Comic(url)`, which then refers back to `struct Comic`.

Answer (score 18):

The other answer explains why this crashes the Julia process; now, to make this work the way you intended, you can simply use an [inner constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods):

```
julia> struct Comic
           endpoint::String
           Comic(id::String) = new("https://xkcd.com/$id/info.0.json")
       end

julia> Comic("1")
Comic("https://xkcd.com/1/info.0.json")
```

This works because `new` doesn't recursively call this constructor (which would lead to the crash). Instead it creates the object directly with the given string as its element.

Another option to consider is the [URIs.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/URIs.jl) package.

```
julia> using URIs

julia> struct XComic
          endpoint::URI
       end

julia> XComic(id::String) = XComic(URI("https://xkcd.com/$id/info.0.json"))
XComic

julia> XComic("4")
XComic(URI("https://xkcd.com/4/info.0.json"))
```

Comment: I did not notice the dollar `$` sign within the `String` ;) in that case that is to be removed

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated. I should've asked how to fix it in my original question.