# How to refer the struct itself in Julia

Tags: struct, julia

I have this code:

```
struct MyStruct
    text::String
    
    function MyStruct(_text::String)
        text = _text
        # do other things
    end
end
```

When I wrote this, I realized that Julia is not recognizing `text` as `MyStruct`'s field. How can I do something like this in Julia like in Python?

```
self.text = _text
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to imitate Python.  Julia is not object oriented.

You could emulate a Python-style constructor by

```
mutable struct MyStruct
    text::String
    
    function MyStruct(text::String)
        self = new()
        self.text = some_stuff(text)
        return self
    end
end
```

but for this to work the struct needs to be mutable.  Then you can set up an uninitialize instance with `new()` and overwrite the fields.

Note that this is more equivalent to a combination of both `__init__` and `__new__`.  In Python, the `new` part is (99% of the time) already done for you, and you just mutate the already created empty object in `__init__`.  In Julia, you have to do both on your own; this especially also requires returning the new value at the end of the constructor!

Having said all this, it's not often useful to write that way.  More idiomatic would be just

```
struct MyStruct
    text::String

    MyStruct(text::String) = new(some_stuff(text))
end
```

unless you absolutely need the struct to be mutable (which has consequences with respect to memory layout and possible optimizations).

And also read up on the difference between inner and outer constructors.  If you want the above to be the only valid way to construct `MyStruct`, this is fine.  If you want "convenience constructors", e.g. with default arguments or conversions from other types, prefer outer constructors (where you don't have `new` but recursively call constructors until an inner constructor is reached).

Answer (score 3):

Taking a quick glance at the [constructors documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/) and trying out the [playground](https://code.labstack.com/julia), I was able to come up with this:

```
struct MyStruct
    text::String   
    function MyStruct(_text::String)
        s = new(_text * "def")
        # do other things
        s
    end
end

s = MyStruct("abc")
println(s.text)     # abcdef
```

Comment: This is correct. Because Julia is not object-oriented, there is no "self" to refer to inside the function. If your constructor had a different signature, for eg. `MyStruct(textasint::Integer)`, you can just define that outside the `struct` and call `MyStruct(string(textasint))` from within that, which would have called the default constructor. Here, because your constructor takes a `String` itself and overrides the default constructor, you have to use an "Inner constructor" and use `new`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69980738/8127).

Comment: It's not entirely the same, as you can't say `s.text = "bla"` in the `#do other things` part, since the struct is not mutable.

Comment: @SundarR: I feel always strange when one claims "Julia is not object-oriented" when EVERYTHING in julia is indeed an object... it surelly is multiple paradigm, and implement oo programming somehow differently .

Comment: @Antonello when I claim something like that, I mean it in the sense of "not object oriented like Jave/Python/...". In Julia, code is not associated with objects; it is not the objects who react to messages ("have methods"), but functions who do dispatch (e.g., can be no "bound functions" like `"x".__len__`). Structs can be thought of as C-like. If at all, Julia is as object oriented as [CLOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) is, but few people nowadays would consider this the same thing.