# Get struct property from inside struct function errors out

Tags: julia

Recently started to try and learn Julia through examples. I am basically trying to figure out how to access a `struct` property from within a function inside the `struct` itself. E.g:

```
struct Test
    a::Int
    foo::Function

    function Test()
        return new(777, xfoo)
    end

    function xfoo()
        println(a)
    end
end

t = Test()
t.foo()
```

I get:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: a not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#xfoo#1")()
   @ Main /tmp/j.jl:10
 [2] top-level scope
   @ /tmp/j.jl:15
in expression starting at /tmp/j.jl:15
```

Am I using Julia wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: This may be of some help: [How to refer the struct itself in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70572532/13843268).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia is not object oriented language so object oriented patterns are usually not a good idea.

Hence `xfoo` should be outside of `Test`:

```
function xfoo(t::Test)
    println(t.a)
end
```

There are packages that try to emulate OOP with Julia (however this is not a Julian pattern): https://github.com/Suzhou-Tongyuan/ObjectOriented.jl

You can also easily find quite a lot of discussion behind the design decision no to make Julia OOP. Start with: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-there-is-no-oop-object-oriented-programming-in-julia/86723

#### Workaround

Just out of curiosity one can find some workaround to attach a function to a `struct` (not a recommended design pattern!). For an example:

```
mutable struct MyTest
    a::Int
    foo::Function
    function MyTest()
        s = Ref{MyTest}()
        s[] = new(777, () -> println(s[].a))
        s[]
    end
end
```

And some sample usage:

```
julia> t = MyTest();

julia> t.foo()
777

julia> t.a = 900;

julia> t.foo()
900
```